# How to use a return value from a procedure in another procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am new to databases and sql-server 2008. I have a procedure which looks something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P @myint as int
AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #temp (Quantity smallint, Timing smallint)

INSERT INTO #temp

SELECT 
    Order.quantity as 'Quantity',
    Order.ValidUntil - Order.ValidFrom / X

FROM
    Order

WHERE 
    Order.id = 123

SELECT * FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp

END
```

Now the problem is in the above select statement in second column where i mentioned 'X'. For this X i should have a value after executing another procedure which returns a table and i want to use values from certain column of that table.

So, instead of X i want to write something like

```
create table #tmp (col1 nvarchar(512), col2 smalldatetime, col3 smalldatetime, col4 int, col5 float)
Insert into #tmp EXEC ProcedureHere 6, '20130101', '20131231', 0, 400
select col4 from #tmp
```

Comment: instead of procedure, could you create a function that returns table??

Comment: no, this has to be done with procedure. Its a design decision.

Comment: Make sure you read [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html), which explains in great detail the options you have for sharing data between stored procdures

Answer (score 1):

In your procedure you must put the parameters with the output attribute, when you define the parameter as OUT/OUTPUT the value will be available after the procedure execution finish.

```
--first declare all variables with the same type as table #tmp fields     
--remember: It's a better design put the declare block in the top of the procedure
declare @p1 nvarchar(512), 
        @p2 smalldatetime, 
        @p3 smalldatetime,
        @p4 int,
        @p5 float

--create the table  
create table #tmp (col1 nvarchar(512), col2 smalldatetime, col3 smalldatetime, col4 int, col5 float)

--call the procedure
EXEC ProcedureHere @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5             

--insert data into temporary table
Insert into #tmp 
  select @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5

--read col4 
select col4 from #tmp 
--or 
select @p4
```

Procedure DDL:

```
if another parameters is required, you simply add then in the mark (*):
Create Procedure ProcedureHere(
        @p1 nvarchar(512) output, 
        @p2 smalldatetime output, 
        @p3 smalldatetime output,
        @p4 int output,
        @p5 float output,
        *) as
begin
  .
  DoStuff
  .
  --define @p1 result value
  select @p1 = select something from somewhere
  --so on for the others parameters      
  .
end
go
```

Comment: There is a documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: maybe you don't even need a temporary table